# How to attach .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile to my setup project?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, deployment, windows-installer, installation

By default, the install location for prerequisites of `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64)` is from the Microsoft web site, which requires the client network to be available during installation.

I am just wondering, is there a way that we can install `.NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64)` without downloading from the vendor's web site? I assume the second option, "Download prerequisites from the same location as my application", is something I should be looking at here. But I am not 100% sure.

Also, in which folder should I place the redistributable file, `dotNetFx40_Client_x86_x64.exe`?

Comment: installer will put all the request files you need to correct folder (near the installer) automatic if you set 2nd option.

Comment: You should already have it, look in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX40Client

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can select second option "Download prerequisites from the same location as my application" to install .NET Framework 4 Client Profile without downloading it from website. But you need to set path for that prerequisites as it done in below link.

**Ref:** *[Error_7_The install location for prerequisites has not been set to 'component vendor's web site' and the file 'DotNetFX40\dotNetFx40LP_Full_x86_x64fr.exe' in item 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 (x86 and x64)' can not be located on disk.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/thread/05cb5b29-b8be-4877-9aaa-8047697b7bf0/)*

**UPDATE:** You need to set below path for .NET Framework 4.0 Client Profile:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX40Client\dotNetFx40_Client_x86_x64.exe

Answer (score 0):

The common setup project and ClickOnce support .NetFX deployment. Have a look at MSDN page *[.NET Framework Deployment Guide for Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942965.aspx)*.